# Extra Line Created Import File

Tags: vb.net

An extra line is being created in my import file which is fed in from another CSV and is going to break my import file. How can I remove the extra line that was created? Thanks!

the code I use to create the file is follows

```
Friend Function ImportFile(ByVal filename As String) As infoEDIProduct()

 Dim retVal() As infoEDIProduct
    Try
        Dim actualFileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
    Catch e1 As IO.IOException
        MsgBox("File is already open please check file.")
    End Try

    Dim streamReader As New IO.StreamReader(filename)
    Dim streamWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(filename & ".csv")
    streamWriter.AutoFlush = True
    streamWriter.WriteLine(TabDeliminatedHeaders)
    Dim lineIn As String = ""
    Do While Not streamReader.EndOfStream
        retVal = Resize(retVal)
        retVal(retVal.Length - 1) = TransformToEDIProduct(streamReader)


        streamWriter.Write(TransformEDIproductIntoTabDeliminated(retVal(retVal.Length - 1)))
    Loop

    streamWriter.Close()
    streamWriter.Dispose()
    streamReader.Close()
    streamReader.Dispose()
    Return retVal


Private Function TransformEDIproductIntoTabDeliminated(ByVal EDIproduct As infoEDIProduct) As String
    Dim retVal As String = ""
    With EDIproduct
        retVal = .lineNumber & vbTab
        retVal &= .UPCcode & vbTab
        retVal &= .sketchersStyleNumber & vbTab
        retVal &= .colourDescription & vbTab
        retVal &= .size & vbTab
        retVal &= .sketchersDivisionDescription & vbTab
        retVal &= .sketchersColourCode & vbTab
        retVal &= .sketchersDivisionCode & vbTab
        retVal &= .department & vbTab
        retVal &= .subDepartment & vbTab
        retVal &= .gender & vbTab
        retVal &= .productShortDescription & vbTab
        retVal &= .productDescription & vbTab
        retVal &= .costPrice & vbTab
        retVal &= .retailPrice & vbTab
        retVal &= .DiscountPrice & vbTab
        retVal &= .GeminiDepartmentId
    End With
    Return retVal
End Function

Private Function TransformProductToEdi(ByVal EDIproduct As infoEDIProduct) As String
    Dim retVal As String = ""
    With EDIproduct
        retVal = .lineNumber & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .UPCcode & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .sketchersStyleNumber & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .colourDescription & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .size & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .sketchersDivisionDescription & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .sketchersColourCode & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .sketchersDivisionCode & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .department & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .subDepartment & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .gender & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .productShortDescription & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .productDescription & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .costPrice & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .retailPrice & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .DiscountPrice & vbCrLf
        retVal &= .GeminiDepartmentId & vbCrLf
    End With
    Return retVal
End Function
```

Comment: where is the extra line in the file?

Comment: @onof at the end of the file

Comment: Where is `TransformToEDIProduct` and `TransformEDIproductIntoTabDeliminated`?  That's where your data is organized.

Comment: @tinstaafl added it in the edit their now

Comment: @tinstaafl it needs to be line by line though if i remove the vbcrlf of retval it mucks up the file

Comment: @LarsTech that is why im asking advice how would i ignore the empty lines?

Comment: It's a little bit confusing because you aren't importing a file, you are creating a file (or transforming a file).  Who is consuming the file you are creating?  That consumer should be a little more robust and just ignore any empty lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is you have to remove the last `vbCrLf` produced by `TransformProductToEdi` for the last entry of the array `retval`

the last line that produce the `vbCrLf` in `TransformProductToEdi` is

```
   retVal &= .GeminiDepartmentId & vbCrLf
```